# Starting Qt/C++ Development for an iOS Developer (obj C)

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, swift, qt

I've been developing iOS apps in Objective C for almost 4 years now (with some Android dev thrown in there too). I have been appointed a new project to develop a cross platform application using Qt/C++ mainly by using Widgets.

I've covered basic C++ and am currently nearing the end of an introductory Qt online course. So far communication between classes has always been done using the Signals and Slots mechanism.

Coming from iOS I'm accustomed to rely on protocols/delegation, notifications and the KVO design pattern. I wonder, is Signals and Slots the only design pattern used communicate between classes when using Qt/C++?

Cheers.

Comment: You can use C++ to implement any way of inter-object communication you wish. The patterns are up to you. You're not limited to what's provided by Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Beyond the pure C++ way of working, Qt introduced the Signals and Slots mechanism. However, Qt 4 introduced a set of item view classes that use the model - view architecture, see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).

Answer (score 0):

Protocols/Delegation is easily implemented in C++.  A protocol is just a class with pure virtual functions.

However, if you are already relying on Qt, I think it makes sense to use its facilities.